How to set projection for Pacific-centered raster
I have a project in QGIS that I need to add a raster file to (.nc). The projection is EPSG:4326, but its boundaries are 0 to 360. How can I center the raster over the Atlantic ocean (180). Or, change the project projection to be centered over the Pacific ocean? See image:
I have many rasters like this, so would need to change several files.


Solved this issue with some Python using rioxarray package. The code will open the .nc file with the raster, then convert extent from (0,360) to (-180,180).
import rioxarray
import xarray as xr

input_fp = 'file.nc'
output_fp = 'corrected_file.tif'

rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(input_fp)

print("Available data variables:", rds.data_vars)
raster_variable_name = 'var_name'

rds_var = rds[raster_variable_name]
rds_var = rds_var.assign_coords(x=(((rds_var.x + 180) % 360) - 180)).sortby('x')
rds_var.rio.to_raster(output_fp)

print(f"GeoTIFF saved as {output_fp}")

